# Get the pointer to an element in a two-dimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

If I have this array:

```
#define a 10
#define b 20

int foo[a][b];
```

I could get the pointer to `foo[i][j]` like this:

```
int *pointerToElement(i, j)
{
    return *foo + i * b + j;
}
```

Isn't there an easier way using index notation (`*foo[i][j]`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
return & foo[i][j];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method is wrong:

```
*foo + i * b + j
```

This dereferences the pointer `foo` and adds something to its value. What you want is:

```
foo + i * b + j
```

And since the index notation also dereferences the pointer, you have to reference it again:

```
&foo[i][j]
```

Comment: Of course: `foo` is pointer to pointer to int, so when dereferenced, it's still a pointer (to int). ) Still this codepad is wrong: you shouldn't play with `[a][b]`; only `[0..a-1][0..b-1]` values are in range. )

Comment: @raina77ow No, `foo` is an `int[10][20]`, not an `int**`, and decays into an `int (*)[20]`, a pointer to array of 20 `int`, in most contexts. So `foo + i*b + j` would produce an `int (*)[20]` at a byte-offset of `(i*b+j)*sizeof(int[20])` behind the first byte of `foo` if `a` were large enough (it isn't, unless `i == 0` and `j` is small enough, or one of the two is negative with appropriate magnitude, so the addition invokes undefined behaviour in general). `*foo` on the other hand is an `int[20]`, and that decays in most contexts into an `int*`, so `*foo + i*b + j` works.